# How to pick pair randomly from Arraylist Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Example I have this ArrayList of object:

```
clusterData: [{BitSet: [1, 1], Entropy: 0.0}, {BitSet: [1, 0], Entropy: 1.0}, {BitSet: [0, 0], Entropy: 0.0}, {BitSet: [0, 0], Entropy: 0.0}, {BitSet: [0, 0], Entropy: 0.0}]
```

and those with similar BitSet and Entropy value will become a possible pair and in this case it produce:
Pair #2 WITH Pair #3
Pair #2 WITH Pair #4
Pair #3 WITH Pair #4

So, from the three produced pair, how can i pick one at random from the three possible pairs and store in another ArrayList?

This is my code:

```
System.out.println("clusterData: " + clusterData);

    for (int i = 0; i < clusterData.size()-1; i++){
        for (int j = i+1; j < clusterData.size(); j++){
            if (clusterData.get(i).getBitSet().equals(clusterData.get(j).getBitSet()) && clusterData.get(i).getEntropy() == clusterData.get(j).getEntropy()){
                System.out.println("Pair #" + i + " WITH Pair #" + j);


            }
        }

    }
```

Please help.

Comment: if they are simlar why do you need choose one randomly? You could just store them in a `Set`, which will get rid of duplicates and add these `Set` to a new `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Take the first one randomly from the entire set. Take the next one from a set that is one smaller (to represent the fact you do not want both numbers the same). If the second one matches or exceeds the first, add one. Then assign to `i` and `j` so that `i < j`.

```
// pick a from set [0..n)
// pick b from set [0..n-1)
//     which can also be represented as two sets
//           [0..a)[a..n-1)
// add one when b >= a, meaning b is in the sets:
//           [0..a)(a..n)

Random r;
int a = r.nextInt(clusterData.size());
int b = r.nextInt(clusterData.size()-1);
if (b >= a)
  b++;
if (a < b) {
  i = a;
  j = b;
} else {
  i = b;
  j = a;
}
```

Comment: Was this any help to you? Please upvote or accept helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add all the possible pairs to a `List` and choose one of it's elements at random.

This code would run in `O(N²)` where `N` is the size of the input data.

---

A more efficient way would be grouping the cluster data to equivalence classes (provided the similarity relation is a equivalence relation, which seems to be the case here [transitivity is important for this approach]).

I'll use `ClusterData` as type name for the element type here.

Override `equals` and `hashCode` of `ClusterData` to return `true`/the same hash code if the cluster data is similar.

Then create a `Map<ClusterData, List<Integer>>` mapping the different `ClusterData` values to a list of the indices of the elements in the `clusterData` list.

```
Map<ClusterData, List<Integer>> equivalenceClasses = IntStream.range(0, clusterData.size()).boxed()
                                                              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(clusterData::get));
```

In the next step count the number of possible pairs:

```
public static int choose2(int elements) {
    return elements * (elements - 1) / 2;
}
```

```
int pairCount = equivalenceClasses.values().stream().mapToInt(lst -> choose2(lst.size())).sum();
```

Decide on one of the equivalence classes where each equivalence class has a probability proportional to the number of pairs it can provide:

```
if (pairCount == 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No valid combinations");
}

Random random = ...

int choice = random.nextInt(pairCount);

List<Integer> classIndices = null;

for (List<Integer> indices : equivalenceClasses.values()) {
    choice -= choose2(indices.size());
    if (choice < 0) {
        classIndices = indices;
        break;
    }
}
```

And finally choose a combination from the equivalence class:

```
int first = random.nextInt(classIndices.size());
int second = random.nextInt(classIndices.size()-1);
if (second >= first) {
    second++;
}
int firstIndex = classIndices.get(first);
int secondIndex = classIndices.get(second);

// TODO: swap indices, if firstIndex needs to be smaller than secondIndex
//       and it's not already the case

System.out.println("Chosen combination: Pair #" + firstIndex + " WITH Pair #" + secondIndex);
```

This should run on `O(N)` and improve performance for large input data.

Comment: That last bit looks very familiar! As your answer is based on mine, perhaps you can point out the flaw in mine that yours fixes.

Comment: @weston: Your answer could choose a pair of non-similar elements.